# How do I create a system with limited if statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, formatting

I'm trying to make a program where three levers control a security access system. The user is asked, for each lever, whether they pull the lever or not. In the end. if the second lever is pulled, the door will not open, but if either the first or third lever is pulled, then the door will open.

The caveat to this problem is that I'm limited to only one if statement and one else statement. I've racked my brains but cannot for the life of me think of a solution that encompasses all the situations with just two statements.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    door_one = str(input("Do you pull the first lever? "))
    door_two = str(input("Do you pull the second lever? "))
    door_three = str(input("Do you pull the third lever? "))
    if door_two == "yes":
        print("The door remains shut.")
    else:
        print("The door opens!")
```

Obviously this code is incorrect but I can't think of how I can reduce the number of statements to satisfy the conditions above

Comment: Can the user pull more than one lever?

Comment: @Aimery The user pulls all three levers, or choose not to pull any. The door shuts if the first or third lever is not pulled, or if the second lever is pulled.

Comment: What's wrong with your code then?

Comment: @Aimery If I type "no" for all the statements, the door still opens, and isn't actually supposed to open.

Comment: In pseudocode: `if (door_one or door_three) and not door_two: print('open')`

Comment: Can't you use Boolean expressions in your conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## UPDATE

Maybe that's what you need to fill:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    door_one = str(input("Do you pull the first lever? "))
    door_two = str(input("Do you pull the second lever? "))
    door_three = str(input("Do you pull the third lever? "))
    if door_two == "yes" or (door_one != 'yes' and door_two != 'yes' and door_three != 'yes'):
        print("The door remains shut.")
    else:
        print("The door opens!")
```

another approach:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    levers = ['first', 'second', 'third']
    lever_vals = []
    for i in levers:
        lever_vals .append(str(input("Do you pull the %s lever? " % i)))
    if lever_vals[1] == 'yes' or all(i != 'yes' for i in lever_vals):
        print("The door remains shut.")
    else:
        print("The door opens!")
```

Comment: Thank you. I did not think of incorporating Boolean operators.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition is that except for `door_two == "yes"`, the result will be `print("The door opens!")`, regardless of `door_two` equal to anything.